# MongoDB Partial Unique Index on Object Field in Array Field

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Lets say I have a collection whose objects have a structure like this:

```
{
  "a": [
    {"name": "foo", "meh": "whatever"}, 
    {"name": "bar", "meh": "hem"}
  ],
  "other_stuff": { }
}
```

It's possible for an object in this collection to *not* have the "a" field. I'd like to enforce a constraint on the database such that, *if* an object has the "a" field, that none of the "name" fields in objects contained in that "a" field are duplicates *across the entire collection*.

So for example, the following object would be flagged as a constraint violation if the above object were already in the collection:

```
{
  "a": [
    {"name": "bar", "meh": "meh meh"}
  ],
  "other_stuff": { }
}
```

Furthermore, the following object would be flagged as a constraint violation regardless of other documents already in the collection:

```
{
  "a": [
    {"name": "boo", "meh": "blub"}, 
    {"name": "boo", "meh": "glub"}
  ],
  "other_stuff": { }
}
```

Is it possible to specify a partial unique index for MongoDB? If it's different between Mongo 3.2, 3.4, 3.6 and 4.0 it would be nice to know that too - I don't care about earlier than 3.2.

I was thinking it might be something like this to prevent duplication across documents (because in Javscript `[] > '' === false` and `undefined > '' === false` and `['anything'] > '' === true` for the passive reader):

```
db.MyCollection.createIndex(
  { "a.name": 1 },
  { 
    "unique": true, 
    "partialFilterExpression": {
      "a": { "$gt": '' }
    }
  }
)
```

... and I *think* the only way to prevent duplicate values within a document is to enforce in application logic the use of the `$addToSet` operator when operating on the "a" field.

I'd be happy to be corrected or corroborated on either count.